# Reducing data in table will help to improve the performance

Tags: oracle11g

Following query executed by product s/w and internal to product. DBA found this query is utilizing more CPU of DB. We can not tweak as this is product specific query , is there any alternative ? consider if we create history / archive table for data in the table will give advantage of following query which uses min and max functions.

```
SELECT MIN(minbkt),
   maxbkt,
   SUBSTRB(DUMP(MIN(val), 16, 0, 32), 1, 120) minval,
   SUBSTRB(DUMP(MAX(val), 16, 0, 32), 1, 120) maxval,
   SUM(rep) sumrep,
   SUM(repsq) sumrepsq,
   MAX(rep) maxrep,
   COUNT(*) bktndv,
   SUM(CASE
           WHEN rep = 1 THEN
            1
           ELSE
            0
       END) unqrep
FROM (SELECT val,
           MIN(bkt) minbkt,
           MAX(bkt) maxbkt,
           COUNT(val) rep,
           COUNT(val) * COUNT(val) repsq
      FROM (SELECT
            /*+ no_parallel(t) no_parallel_index(t) dbms_stats cursor_sharing_exact use_weak_name_resl dynamic_sampling(0) no_monitoring */
             "VERSION_LABEL" val,
             NTILE(75) OVER(ORDER BY NLSSORT("VERSION_LABEL", 'NLS_SORT = binary')) bkt
              FROM "User"."AUDITTRAIL" t
             WHERE "VERSION_LABEL" IS NOT NULL)
     GROUP BY val)
GROUP BY maxbkt
ORDER BY maxbkt
```

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of the question that you posted yesterday.  Are you certain that this is a product-specific query (i.e. something that is built into the application) rather than something Oracle is running to gather statistics?  As David suggested yesterday, this certainly looks like something `DBMS_STATS` runs in which case the right answer would be to tell `DBMS_STATS` not to gather than histogram.

Comment: Yes, Product specific DBA confirms that query executed by product specific process on DB server